# What is the correct way of showing data in the text widget by calling firebase method

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

There is a method which read amounts from firebase and return Future, But when I try to get amount in my text widget. Then it shows Closure: () => Future instead of amount (an int value)

Here is the method code
...

```
Future<int> getUserAmount() async {
 final userRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('usersData')
    .doc(userIds[i])
    .collection('entries');

final querySnapshot = await userRef.get();

for (var doc in querySnapshot.docs) {
  final docData = doc.data();

  final docAmount = docData['amount'] as int;
  amount += docAmount;
}

i++;
if (i < userIds.length) {
  getUserAmount();
}
print('amout is $amount');
return amount;
```

}

...

// Getter

```
Future<int> getTotalAmount() async {
User user = User();
final amount = await user.getUserAmount();
return amount;
```

}

...

where I wanna show amount from firebase
...

```
FutureBuilder<int>(
            future: getTotalAmount(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                // Show a loading spinner while waiting for the future to complete
                return const CircularProgressIndicator();
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                // Show an error message if the future encounters an error
                return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
              } else {
                return MyTextWidget(
                  text: '$getTotalAmount()',
                  isTitle: true,
                  textSize: 40,
                );
              }
            }),
...
```

Output
[Unexpected output in the emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/te5u0.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getTotalAmount()` is a future method.

this is wrong:

```
 else {
   return MyTextWidget(
       text: '$getTotalAmount()',
       isTitle: true,
       textSize: 40,
   );
}
```

use the `snapshot` instead
like this:

```
 else {
   return MyTextWidget(
       text: '${snapshot.data}',
       isTitle: true,
       textSize: 40,
   );
}
```